# How to change a numeric ID into a sentence in Graylog using pipelines?

Tags: graylog2, graylog, graylog3

I am trying to "beautify" the data I receive from some windows logs on Graylog. My idea is to change the windows log ID from a number to the actual definition for that ID. For example: I receive a log with ID *4625*, I want to show in my widget *"An account failed to log on"*.

To do that, I am using a pipeline and a lookup table, which reads the IDs and the respective definitions in natural language from a .csv that I've uploaded on the server.

This is the rule that I wrote for my pipeline, that doesn't seem to work:

```
rule "eventid_windows_rule"

when

  has_field("winlogbeat_winlog_event_id")

then

let winlogbeat_winlog_italiano = lookup("winlogbeat_winlog_event_id", to_string($message.winlogbeat_winlog_event_id));

set_field("winlogbeat_winlog_italiano", winlogbeat_winlog_italiano);

end
```

I think my problem is specifically in this rule, because Graylog allows to test the lookup tables, and if I manually write an ID, the lookup table finds the respective description.

Comment: Can you show us the `Lookup Result`, when you test your lookup table ?

Comment: Thank you @Swisstone for your help, but yesterday I was able to find the solution myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself, this is the correct code for the rule:

```
rule "eventid_windows_rule"

when

  has_field("winlogbeat_winlog_event_id")

then

let winlogbeat_winlog_italiano = lookup("eventid_widget_windows_lookup", $message.winlogbeat_winlog_event_id);

set_field("winlogbeat_winlog_italiano", winlogbeat_winlog_italiano);

end
```

This rule checks if the log has the field *"winlogbeat_winlog_event_id"*, then it generates the new field *"winlogbeat_winlog_italiano"*, associates the numeric value of *"winlogbeat_winlog_event_id"* with the description in natural language thanks to the .csv that I've created, then puts the description in the field *"winlogbeat_winlog_italiano"*.

[image]